# How to set IntelliJ-Idea Python projects to see OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, intellij-idea

I am trying to use IntelliJ (on Mac) for my Python projects.
Everything works with the exception of OpenCV.

```
import numpy
import scipy
import cv2

print 'Numpy version:\t'+str(numpy.__version__)
print 'Numpy version:\t'+scipy.__version__
print 'OpenCV version:\t'+cv2.__version__
```

This simple code execute well from the terminal command line (since I set the PYTHONPATH in my .bash_profile), but it fails when I try to run it from within IntelliJ.

Anybody has done this ?

Comment: It can be problematic to use a Java IDE to do Python things. I believe you are better off with the Community Edition of [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/). Or Professional if you want to shell out some cash. But I think Community Edition will suit your needs for now.